# I want to set a es7 cluster in k8s,but find a warn nslookup es7-cluster-2.es7-cluster.dj-cp-storage.svc.cluster.local sh: nslookup: command not found

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes

My configuration seems to be OK, and GPT can't see the problem, but the console reports the following errors
一、ERROR:
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2023-07-31T05:54:19,733Z", "level": "WARN", "component": "o.e.d.SeedHostsResolver", "cluster.name": "es-cluster", "node.name": "es7-cluster-2", "message": "failed to resolve host [es7-cluster-0.es7-cluster.dj-cp-storage.svc.cluster.local]",

{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2023-07-31T05:54:20,734Z", "level": "WARN", "component": "o.e.d.SeedHostsResolver", "cluster.name": "es-cluster", "node.name": "es7-cluster-2", "message": "failed to resolve host [es7-cluster-2.es7-cluster.dj-cp-storage.svc.cluster.local]",

二、k8s

1、configmap

```
kind: ConfigMap
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: es-cluster-config
  namespace: dj-cp-storage
  annotations:
    kubesphere.io/creator: wangluwei
data:
  elasticsearch.yml: |
    cluster.name: es-cluster 
    discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 3
    discovery.seed_hosts:
      es7-cluster-0.es7-cluster.dj-cp-storage.svc.cluster.local,es7-cluster-1.es7-cluster.dj-cp-storage.svc.cluster.local,es7-cluster-2.es7-cluster.dj-cp-storage.svc.cluster.local
    cluster.initial_master_nodes:
      es7-cluster-0,es7-cluster-1,es7-cluster-2
    path.logs: /usr/share/elasticsearch/logs`
`

2、service
```

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
name: es7-cluster
namespace: dj-cp-storage
spec:
selector:
app: elasticsearch7
type: NodePort
ports:

- name: http
  port: 9200
  targetPort: 9200
  nodePort: 30920
- name: tcp
  port: 9300
  targetPort: 9300
  nodePort: 30930

```
3、pod
```

apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
name: es7-cluster
namespace: dj-cp-storage
spec:
serviceName: elasticsearch7
replicas: 3
selector:
matchLabels:
app: elasticsearch7
template:
metadata:
labels:
app: elasticsearch7
spec:
affinity:
podAffinity:
requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
- labelSelector:
matchExpressions:
- key: app
operator: In
values:
- elasticsearch7
topologyKey: "kubernetes.io/hostname"
tolerations:
- key: node-role.kubernetes.io/master
operator: Exists
effect: NoSchedule
volumes:
- name: config-volume-elasticsearch-yml
configMap:
name: es-cluster-config
items:
- key: elasticsearch.yml
path: elasticsearch.yml
- name: config-volume-jvm-options
configMap:
name: es-cluster-config
items:
- key: jvm.options
path: jvm.options

```
  containers:
  - name: elasticsearch7
    image: elasticsearch:7.17.7
    ports:
    - containerPort: 9200
      name: rest
      protocol: TCP
    - containerPort: 9300
      name: inter-node
      protocol: TCP
    volumeMounts:
    - name: data
      mountPath: /usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    - name: logs
      mountPath: /usr/share/elasticsearch/logs
    - name: plugins
      mountPath: /usr/share/elasticsearch/plugins
    - name: config-volume-elasticsearch-yml
      mountPath: /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml
      subPath: elasticsearch.yml
      readOnly: true
    - name: config-volume-jvm-options
      mountPath: /usr/share/elasticsearchconfig/jvm.options
      subPath: jvm.options
      readOnly: true
    env:`your text`
    - name: node.name
      valueFrom:
        fieldRef:
          fieldPath: metadata.name
    resources:
      limits:
        memory: 4Gi
        cpu: "3000m"
      requests:
        memory: 4Gi
        cpu: "100m"
  initContainers:
  - name: fix-permissions
    image: busybox
    command: ["/bin/sh", "-c", "chown -R 1000:1000 /usr/share/elasticsearch/data /usr/share/elasticsearch/logs"]
    securityContext:
      privileged: true
    volumeMounts:
    - name: data
      mountPath: /usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    - name: logs
      mountPath: /usr/share/elasticsearch/logs
  - name: increase-vm-max-map
    image: busybox
    command: ["sysctl", "-w", "vm.max_map_count=262144"]
    securityContext:
      privileged: true
  - name: increase-fd-ulimit
    image: busybox
    command: ["sh", "-c", "ulimit -n 65536"]
```

volumeClaimTemplates:

- metadata:
  name: data
  spec:
  accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]
  storageClassName: "es-local-storage"
  resources:
  requests:
  storage: 10Gi
- metadata:
  name: logs
  spec:
  accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]
  storageClassName: "es-local-storage"
  resources:
  requests:
  storage: 4Gi
- metadata:
  name: plugins
  spec:
  accessModes: [ "ReadWriteMany" ]
  storageClassName: "es-local-storage"
  resources:
  requests:
  storage: 1Gi

```
i want cluster can look up each ,and NOT WARNING
```